Rails 7 link_to always triggers Turbo Stream for POST request, even with data: { turbo: false }
In my Rails 7 app, I'm trying to make a link_to trigger a normal POST request, but it always ends up sending a Turbo Stream request. I've tried disabling Turbo by adding data: { turbo: false }, but that doesn't seem to work.
On the other hand, when I use button_to, it correctly performs a regular HTML form POST submission. I want to understand why link_to behaves this way and how I can make it do a normal POST without Turbo interference.

I used the following link_to code with method: :post and data: { turbo: false }, expecting it to submit a normal HTML form POST request:
<%= link_to 'Submit', some_path, method: :post, data: { turbo: false } %>
Expected: A regular HTML POST request without Turbo Stream (no AJAX).
Actual result: It still triggers a Turbo Stream POST request.

I also tried using button_to, and it behaves as expected, submitting a regular HTML form POST request:
<%= button_to 'Submit', some_path %>
Expected and actual result: A normal HTML POST request (this worked fine).

Why does link_to trigger a Turbo Stream POST even with data: { turbo: false }?

How can I force link_to to perform a regular HTML POST request, like button_to?

Why does button_to work fine while link_to doesn't?





This is a deliberate change in rails 7. You can try this.. <%= link_to 'Submit', some_path(format: :html), method: :post, data: { turbo: false } %>

because you're using Rails UJS. there is no need for it if you're using turbo. why do you need html POST instead of turbo stream POST?

I wanted a normal HTML request because the action was meant to redirect to a new page. I thought an HTML POST would handle this better than a Turbo Stream POST.

Turbo Stream POST can handle it just as well.

One way of forcing redirects from turbo requests is adding {format: :html} in the route menhod: redirect_to my_route_path(..., format: :html). IDK if this is TheRightWay™, but it works. So you have have a turbo request, and you can make the browser to redirect using this option.

Turbo doesn't define an event listener for data-method so it's going to do absolutely nothing unless you have Rails UJS present. Instead it listens for events on data-turbo-method as all the Turbo data attributes are namespaced. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#method

"Why does button_to work fine while link_to doesn't?" button_to creates an actual form instead of using javascript to make an <a> element do something it was never designed to do. It's generally preferable for accessibility reasons.

data-turbo=false is not working because link_to still converts the method option to a data-method attribute, which is handled by UJS.
UJS is deprecated and doesn't know about Turbo.
In Rails 7, this particular UJS feature has been replaced by data-turbo-method, which does something very similar.  As the name suggests however, it is going to use Turbo.
I'm afraid that you're not going to be able to both use Rails' built-in JavaScript features & also bypass Turbo, because all built-in JavaScript in Rails 7 is Turbo.
Regarding the statement

it always ends up sending a Turbo Stream request

That's not exactly correct.  Turbo will add the text/vnd.turbo-stream.html mime type to the request, but that just means that a Turbo-Stream response is acceptable.  Your controller action is still free to respond how ever you'd like it to.
to answer your original question, you may be able to add data-local=true or data-remote=false to your link, but I would really advise against using deprecated UJS features if at all possible.
